# Xfce window manager: restore/un-maximize window with keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager, xfce

I have the Xfce panel on top and the "hide title bar when maximized" option enabled in Window Manager Tweaks.
I can unmaximize/restore a maximized window with right click on that window's panel field and selecting "restore", but I'd like to define a key for that, like F9 or something.
Unfortunately I can't find an option like "restore window" under the keyboard tab in window manager settings.
Do we have this option in Xfwm, or is it just missing?

Comment: Try Alt+F10. I believe that un-maximizes it by default.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @n8te for the hint!

<kbd>Alt + F10</kbd>, listed as the default shortcut for *Maximize Window* in Xfce's Window Manager dialog.  However, it's actually a toggle.

When a window is already maximized, it does the opposite (unmaximize), much like F11 with full screen. I was able to change it to just F10 the same way the other shorcuts can be customized!